# getting the sum of previous column elements in the next column in the table

Tags: ios, sqlite, xcode4.5

I have a project of creating an expense manager in iOS using SQLite, so I would like to know about the feasibility of SQLite in my project. I just want to create a table as below

```
id:  categories:      individual expense:     total expense:
1    food                    50 
2    transportation          20
3    fuel                    500                570
```

I need to get the total expense to get saved in the next column when the user enters their expense in the corresponding field, so that I can later refer this total expense column to subtract it from money to find the money left in the pocket of user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be possible to have the total expenses stored in the database, but that would just duplicate information and introduce the risk of inconsistencies.

Typically, you store only the raw data (ID/category/expense) in the database, and compute statistics on the fly with a query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Expense) AS TotalExpense FROM MyTable
```

Comment: thanks for the help sir. if you could please elaborate your statement so that i can change the way i do.sir is that possible to save this value in database so that i can get the total expense at my homepage every time when i launch the app.